# Prove that every simple planar which is **connected** can be coloured with 6 or less colour.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that every simple planar which is **connected** can be coloured with 6 or less colour. I heard a very similar theorem which doesn't have the connected condition.

(Hints in the book:using the fact that simple planar which is **connected** has a vertex which is degree smaller than or equal to 5 and apply mathematical induction on the number of vertices of the graph.)

Attempts: I have tried to use Mathematical induction by assumimg the graph of r vertice is true. But when considering r+1, a problem come. I first want to, say remove the vertix which has degree smaller than or equal to 5 (there exist at least one)and the edges connected to it, but it will return to a subgraph with vertice r, however i found that the reduced graph may not be connected, and once it is disconnected, we cannot apply the induction assumption. So how should I prove the theorem?

Comment: A simple planar graph that is disconnected is just the disjoint union of simple planar graphs that are connected, so we can add connectivity without loss of generality. That is, if you can color a connected component in six or less colors, then you can similarly color the entire graph.

Comment: Every planar *what*? What is M.I? The singular is vertex, plural vertices.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo O, M.I means mathematical induction to me

Comment: @john You have it right.  Just prove the stronger: the graph need not be connected.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are asking if a simple planar graph can be colored with **six or more colors NOT less.**

Notation : $m$ - number of edges, $n$ - number of vertices.

A graph is planar implies it has a vertex $v$ such that $degree(v) \leq 5$. This result is unconnected to whether the graph is connected or disconnected but is related to the fact that planar graphs has an upper bound on the number of edges $m \leq 3(n-2)$. Euler's formula does only apply for connected planar but the inequality $m \leq 3(n-2)$ holds for connected and disconnected graphs. This can be seen by adding edges to disconnected planar graph till it is connected, such that new edge count $m^+ > m$. Then since the new graph is now a connected planar graph $m^+ \leq 3(n-2)$ therefore the original edge count $m < 3(n-2)$.

The fact that a vertex exits in disconnected or connected planar graphs of $degree(v) \leq 5$ be proven by contradiction.
For contradiction assume there exists a planar graph with $degree(v) \geq 6$ for all vertices. Then $2m = \sum{degree(v)} \geq 6n$ or $m \geq 3n$. which is inconsistent with $m \leq 3n-6$.

The proof of the six coloring follows the lines you stated:
By induction you can assume graphs of order $n$ can be colored with 6 colors. Then consider a graph $G$ of order $n+1$. Since $G$ is planar it contains a vertex with degree less than 5. Then consider the graph $G-v$. Since $G-v$ is planar and of order $n$ it must have a 6 coloring. Since $degree(v) \leq 5$ we can use the sixth color to color $v$ in $G$ thus producing a 6 coloring.

But notice we never assumed that the graph is connected. Since we proved a more general result for all planar graph it applies equally to connected and disconnected graphs.